# Looping C compilation and running through BASH

Tags: c, linux, bash, parallel-processing

I'm trying to compile and run a C code while looping the input file through bash. Here is my code for the bash script I am using to automate it.

```
 ~!/bin/bash
 file=1
 outfile='outputnumber'$file
 readsfile='readsfilename'$file'.txt'
 compilefile=compiler$file'.o'
 gcc -lgsl -lgslcblas -std=c99 filewithccode.c -o $compilefile
 echo "Compilation over"
./$compilefile  $outfile $readsfile
```

So what I'm basically trying to do is compile filewithcode.c so that the executable is stored as compiler1, which takes outputnumber1 and readsfilename1.txt as input. The reason I want to do this is so that I can loop it over "file" and automate it for multiple files (I have 45 of them) and automate the execution. But I'm getting the error:

```
Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./$compilefile $outfile $readsfile
```

I am trying to use different names for the compiled file because I am trying to run them parallelly on a server and I am not sure if compiling with the same output name will cause an issue.

Any suggestions? I know that maybe the `"./$"` is causing that error, because the BASH is echoing "Compilation over".

Comment: `I am trying to use different names for the compiled file because I am trying to run them parallelly on a server and I am not sure if compiling with the same output name will cause an issue.` No, it won't. Compile it once and launch it as often as you require, each one with different command line parameters if necessary. Most likely the cause of the SIGSEGV is inside the `C` code, which you have not shown us.

Comment: why don't you echo ./$compilefile  $outfile $readsfile  to make sure everything is running fine, also the problem might be with the executable itself, have you encountered any problems running this manually?

Comment: Agree that the segfault is coming from your C.  Just because it compiles doesn't mean it won't segfault, especially if you're using gcc to compile.  Have you tried compiling manually and running outside of the loop and bash script to test?

Comment: Why are you appending a `.o` extension to the name of the executable output file? That extension is normally used for object files, not executable files.

Comment: @tadamhicks please explain "especially if you're using gcc to compile"

Comment: I only mean to imply there are other C compilers out there that have more built in checking for seg fault prone code ;)

Comment: First and foremost: `~!/bin/bash` is not a shebang. Arguably, it may just be a question typo. Second: the error message didn't expand the variables `Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./$compilefile $outfile $readsfile`. Something must not be right in the script in itself. The usual error should be `Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./compiler1.o outputnumber1 readsfilename1.txrt`.

Comment: @AndreasFester - you are absolutely right. But a poorly written C code can circumvent that. By using a temporary file named after the executable, then having the same executable executed multiple times will cause all of them to use the same temporary file.

Comment: @AndreasFester: I'm sure it is not in the C code since I am able to compile and execute it by itself. My problem has been with the BASH file.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Now that you mention it, I'm not exactly sure why I did that. I guess I was trying to set '.out' as the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line, being that it's just variables placed on a line might cause problems with your script being able to interpret it properly. You might try making it into a string, and then using the exec command on that string. for example:

```
comm="./""$compilefile $outfile $readsfile"
exec $comm
```

This has saved me a lot of syntax trouble with referencing variables in the past.